# Wireless mouse looses connectivity

Tags: mouse

On an HP dv7-1260 laptop with a Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 4000, after upgrading to 16.10 from 16.04, mouse connectivity sometimes goes away after sitting idle for a while.
This does not happen all the time and the trackpad mouse still works. If I reboot, the wireless mouse is active again, sometimes the rest off the day. (I usually shut the laptop off each night)
Could this be something in the 16.10 upgrade or coincidentally a component of the mouse (receiver or transmitter) has started to go bad? I replaced the battery with a new one but it still occurs .